# How to get the value of a JSON property in Elixir

Tags: json, elixir

I'm returning this kind os data to an variable:

`{"numbers":[0.8832325122263557,0.9905363563950811, ...]}`

How can i remove this string "numbers": and stay just with the [] ?

Comment: I see, i'm scraping a site, so the data comes like this, don't you think i can make something of it ?

Comment: Is this JSON data and not an Elixir term?

Comment: No, I'm just scraping this page: http://challenge.dienekes.com.br/api/numbers?page=1

Comment: That is JSON data, so you're going to want a JSON parser. A popular one is Jason (https://hexdocs.pm/jason). It'll let you decode that JSON string into a map with a key `"numbers"` pointing to a list of floats. If you just want the list of floats you can then do a map get/fetch.

Comment: Awesome, I'll try this, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a script that

1. Uses [`Mix.install/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/1.12/Mix.html#install/2) to instal [Jason](https://hexdocs.pm/jason/Jason.html). In a mix project you would add `jason` to your deps in `mix.exs` instead.
2. Uses the [`~S` sigil](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#sigil_S/2) to quote the JSON without needing to escape the `"` characters.
3. Uses [`Jason.decode!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/jason/Jason.html#decode!/2) to parse the JSON.
4. Uses [`Map.get/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Map.html#get/3) to get the value of the `numbers` key from the resulting map.
5. Inspects the value with [`IO.inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#inspect/2), causing it to print out.
6. Uses [`|>` pipes](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#%7C%3E/2) to pass the data between function calls succinctly.

```elixir
Mix.install([:jason])

~S({"numbers":[0.8832325122263557,0.9905363563950811]})
|> Jason.decode!()
|> Map.get("numbers")
|> IO.inspect()
```

Running and output:

```sh
$ elixir example.exs
[0.8832325122263557, 0.9905363563950811]
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks. in my case i receive the full json in a variable, how can I use it on the sutil expression?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. If you replace the `~S()` sigil above with your json variable, it should do the same thing. You can put more `IO.inspect` calls between the lines to see what is happening at each step.

Comment: Yeah, it worked, Thanks a lot! now i'm trying to append this final result (from many pages) to an other table, do you know which command should i use?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem :) As for the second question, I think you should ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

Just to propose an alternative solution without a JSON parser, I would use [`Regex`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Regex.html#scan/3).

1. Captures any string inside brackets, e.g. `[numbers]`
2. Splits the string by `,`
3. Converts the string numbers to floats

```
string = ~S({"numbers":[0.8832325122263557,0.9905363563950811]})

~r/(?:.+\[)(?'numbers'.+)(?:\].+)/
|> Regex.scan(string, capture: ["numbers"])
|> List.first()
|> List.first()
|> String.split(",")
|> Enum.map(&String.to_float/1)
```

This works well if your input is always expected to be like `{"numbers":[0.8832325122263557,0.9905363563950811, ...]}`.